Proof of grz theorem
I am studying Boolos' The Logic of Provability and tried (and failed) to make  a tree proof of the following formula (page 163 5th remark on Grz)
$$\mathbf{GL}\vdash\boxdot(\boxdot(p\rightarrow\boxdot p)\rightarrow p)\rightarrow p$$
where $\boxdot A$ denotes $\Box A\land A$.
The book gives a Hilbert style proof of it, but I wanted to make a truth tree proof. (As explained in the book chapter 10)
The formula is the axiom for provability logic Grz.
When I try the tree doesnt close while the complete tree should close.
below my new complete proof
can you spot the mistake?

tree proof of GL|- [#]([#](P ->[#] P)-> P)-> P
world w0
1       x  -[#]([#](P ->[#] P)->P)-> P
2    1  x  [#]([#](P ->[#]P) ->P)
3    1     -P
4    2     [ ](# ->P)
5    2  x  [#](P ->[#]P) -> P
6    5  x  [#](P ->[#]P) v P
7    6  x  .. .. .. .. . v P  ---> closes with -P (line 3)
8    6  x  -[#](P ->[#]P)
9    8  x  -[ ](P ->[#]P) v -(P ->[#]P)
10   9  x  .. .. .. .. .. v (P & -[#]P)
11  10  x  .. .. .. .. .. v P  ----> closes with -P (3)
12   8     -[ ](P ->[#]P)
remaining from world w0
3    1     -P
4    2     [ ](# ->P)
12   8     -[ ](P ->[#]P)  --> new world w1
world closes when world w1 closes


World w1 opened from world w0
1   w0  x  -(P ->[#]P)
2   w0     [ ](P ->[#]P)
3   w0  x  [#](P ->[#]P) -> P
4   w0     [ ]([#](P ->[#]P) ->P)
5    1  x  P & -[#]P
6    5     P
7    5  x  -[#]P
8    7  x  -[ ]P v -P
9    7  x  .. .. v -P  ---> closes with P (line 6)
10   7     -[ ]P
11   3  x  -# v P
12  11  x  .. .. .. .. .. v P ----> closes line 11
remaining from world w1
2   w0     [ ](P ->[#]P)
4   w0     [ ]([#](P ->[#]P) ->P)
6    5     P
10   7     -[ ]P --> new world w2
world closes when world w2 closes


World w2 opened from world w1
1   w1     -P 
2   w1     [ ]P 
3   w0  x  P -> [#]P 
4   w0     [ ](P ->[#]P)
5   w0  x  [#](P ->[#]P) -> P
6   w0     [ ]([#](P ->[#]P) ->P)
7   3   x  -P v [#]P 
8   7   x  -P   ---> closes 7 by line 1
9   5   x  -[#](P ->[#]P) v P
10  9   x  .. .. .. .. .. v P ---> closes by line 1
11  9   x  -[#](P ->[#]P) 
12  11  x  -[ ](P ->[#]P) v -(P ->[#]P) 
13  12  x  .. .. .. .. .. v -(P ->[#]P) 
14  13  x  .. .. .. .. .. v P & -[#]P 
15  14  x  .. .. .. .. .. v P ---> closes by line 1
12  12     -[ ](P ->[#]P) 
remaining from world w2
1   w1     -P
2   w1     [ ]P
4   w0     [ ](P ->[#]P)
6   w0     [ ]([#](P ->[#]P) ->P)
12  12     -[ ](P ->[#]P)  --> new world w3
world closes when world w3 closes


World w3 opened from world w2
1   w2   x  P ->[#]P 
2   w2      [ ](P ->[#]P)
3   w1      P 
4   w1      [ ]P 
5   w0   x  P ->[#]P
6   w0   x  [ ](P ->[#]P) duplicate 2
7   w0   x  [#](P ->[#]P) -> P
8   w0      [ ]([#](P ->[#]P) ->P)
9    1   x  [#]P   mp 3 1
10   9   x  [ ]P & P
11  10   x  [ ]P   duplicate 4
11  10   x  p      duplicate 3
12   7   x  -[#](P ->[#]P) v P
13  12   x  .. .. .. .. .. v P duplicate 3
remaining from world w3
2   w2      [ ](P ->[#]P)
3   w1      P
4   w1      [ ]P
8   w0      [ ]([#](P ->[#]P) ->P)
open ????


What are your tree rules for $\sf GL$? From what I’ve seen, you need to use the following rule for Diamonds: “from $\Diamond A,w$, open a new world $v$ such that we have $A,v$ and $\Box \neg A, v$. This is because $\Diamond A \leftrightarrow \Diamond (A \land \Box \neg A)$ holds in $\sf GL$.

The tree rules as you give them  and also []A ->[](A & []A) (transitivity or K4 rule) but i would not use the diamond at all just use it as -[]A -> <>( -A & []A)

You must be doing something wrong then.

Boolos's exposition of the truth-tree method for provability logic is indeed quite unclear, or, he might be said to assume too much.
I shall give non-$\boxdot$ demonstration, for the $\boxdot$-version would be too tedious to set down here. However, this should not present a difficulty, because it would be an extension with the straightforward application of the method of  semantic tableaux for propositional calculus.
Actually, there is a translation between $\mathbf{Grz}$ and $\mathbf{GL}$ such that
$$\mathbf{Grz}\vdash A\iff\mathbf{GL}\vdash A^{\ast}$$
where $A^{\ast}$ is obtained from the formula $A$ by replacing all its subformulas of the form $\Box B$ by $\boxdot B$. Hence, we prove an  equivalent of the formula in question.
I ought to note a few preliminary points. Nevertheless, they are meant just to inform the interested reader about what to follow up. Their Detailed explanations are given in Melvin Fitting and Richard Mendelsohn's First-Order Modal Logic and James Garson's Modal Logic for Philosophers.
The critical stipulation in building a tree which is general to modal logic is that we can pass from one world $w_{i}$ to a new world $w_{i+1}$ that has not occured before only by $\Diamond$-rules. Thus, we can apply $\Box$-rules in a new world $w_{i+1}$ only after it has been introduced by a $\Diamond$-rule. This is the idea of "opening a window onto a possible world" by $\neg\Box C$ (i.e., the modal rule on pp. 141-142).
By the same token, we can write a formula $D$ when we have a formula $\Box D$ staying in the same possible world (again, refer to the modal rule). This rule is used below from passing from line 2 to 4. I indicate the worlds with superscripts to track, beware they are not steps as in the first example in the book.
So, we begin with
$$\mathbf{Grz}\vdash\Box(\Box(p\rightarrow\Box p)\rightarrow p)\rightarrow p$$

$\quad\checkmark\qquad\neg(\Box(\Box(p\rightarrow\Box p)\rightarrow p)\rightarrow p)^{1}$
$\qquad\qquad\Box(\Box(p\rightarrow\Box p)\rightarrow p)^{1}$
$\qquad\qquad\neg p^{1}$
$\quad\checkmark\qquad\Box(p\rightarrow\Box p)\rightarrow p^{1}$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\diagup\qquad\qquad\diagdown$
$\quad\checkmark\qquad\neg\Box(p\rightarrow\Box p)^{1}\qquad\quad p^{1}$
$\quad\checkmark\qquad\neg(p\rightarrow\Box p)^{2}\qquad\quad \times$
$\qquad\qquad\Box(p\rightarrow\Box p)^{2}$
$\qquad\qquad p^{2}$
$\qquad\qquad\neg\Box p^{2}$
$\qquad\qquad\times$


Did you mean to put $\sf Grz.$ instead of $\sf GL$? The Grz. axiom is not a theorem of $\sf GL$.

Thanks, I've corrected it..

thanks but i was looking for the tree proof of my formula, edited my post with where i came to at the moment (proof is still not complete ...
